Kafka topic creation best strategy
Im building a streaming application where I will receive logs of various transactions which need to be processed. Planning to use kafka for this, and Im a newbie to kafka. What are the best practices when choosing a topic for kafka, are they supposed to be static values? Also in my case, each log will have a transaction-id. Can I use the value of transaction-id to generate a new topic when a new unique value of transaction-id is published to kafka?

Is this transactions comes from some database?

No, these get published to kafka from a /post endpoint hosted on kubernetes pods

Creating new topic for each log is not good idea.Are you concerned about the order of transaction consuming from consumer?
